# Group and Count Duplicate Status Messages SQL

Tags: php, mysql

What's the best way of grouping and counting duplicate database records if the details found as bold in the example below match the text of other records?

After my system sends out an email to let me know system status, I end up with a rather lot of emails in my inbox. This I feel would be more benifical as records in a database, but I would like to group and count total duplicate records to enable the details to be compiled as a report.

What would be the best way of carrying out the grouping and counting how? Without dratically gringing the system to a hault to due excessive processing?

**An example message:**

> **/crons/sendMessage.php**, Line No: **234** Ran successfully. **File was included** in **/details/output.php**, Line No: **45**

*Messages can contain completly different script paths/names, and/or line numbers.

Comment: `*Message can contain completly different script paths/names, and line numbers` -

Then by definition they are not duplicates. Further unless all the messages follow *exactly* the format of filenames with paths and line numbers the it's impossible for your program to parse the expression to work out what to treat as the same message. Really it would have helped if you had given a more complete example showing what you define as a "duplicate" and what is not a "duplicate".

Comment: What does your database table/tables look like?  The much harder problem seems to be getting the email into the database.

Comment: So if the message string contains all 5 of the bolded texts, then you want to increment the count by 1?  And in your email it would say:
"You received 15 messages that said this: /crons/sendMessage.php, Line No: 234 Ran successfully. File was included in /details/output.php, Line No: 45"
Is that right?

Comment: @dmikester1 Yes that is correct! You have hit the nail on the head. Even if only 1-2-3 or 4 out of 5 details matches other records then then should be grouped by only these details, and the count incremented and displayed.

Comment: Could split the string and save in a table with columns - `script`, `line_no_1`, `action`, `message`, `line_no_2`. This would make `group by`, etc a lot easier

Comment: @Sean I would like to keep the table simple. Subject, Details and date.

Comment: Can you give 2 sample messages that you would like to see grouped together?

Answer (score 0):

So create a database table with the following fields; MessageID, MessageText, and MessageCount.  In your code, once a message is received, check if it matches your bolded texts by comparing to the MessageText field in your DB.  If it exists, increase count by 1 for that message.  If not, create a new entry with the message at count = 1.  At the end of the day, have a PHP script run that crawls your database table and emails you the results and then emptys the table.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm after. I'm looking to do this all on the fly, therefore just saving the subject, details, and date in the database. I need the duplicates count and grouping to take place on the fly so the results can be pagified. This is what I'm struggling with?

Comment: What do you mean by pagified?  You just want a summary email right?